# How to enter data from a form on one sheet onto a log on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm trying to figure out how I can setup a macro that will take the data that I enter into a form on one sheet then log it into a log in another sheet. It will log it but my big problem is that it needs to go to the next line and I can't quite figure out the code for it. Here is what my code looks like:

```
Sub Appt()


'
' Appt Macro
'
'

Range("E4").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Appointments").Select
Range("G7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Data Entry").Select
Range("E6").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Appointments").Select
Range("D7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Data Entry").Select
Range("E8").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Appointments").Select
Range("E7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Data Entry").Select
Range("E10").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Appointments").Select
Range("F7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Data Entry").Select
Range("E12").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Appointments").Select
Range("H7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Data Entry").Select
Range("E4").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents
Range("E6").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("E8").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("E10").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("E12").Select
Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the next empty row on Sheets("Appointments") you would use this formula to get the row number:

```
 tRw = Sheets("Appointments").Range("D" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
```

This assumes that there is nothing in column D below what you are pasting.

It is apparent that you used the macro recorder, and this is a great way to learn.  But using the `.select` so much will slow things down and is unneeded.

To get around that declare the sheets as variables and then one line for each copy paste is needed.

```
Sub APPT()
Dim oWs As Worksheet
Dim tWs As Worksheet
Dim tRw As Long

Set oWs = Sheets("Data Entry")
Set tWs = Sheets("Appointments")
tRw = tWs.Range("D" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

With oWs
    .Range("E4").copy tWs.Range("G" & tRw)
    .Range("E6").copy tWs.Range("D" & tRw)
    .Range("E8").copy tWs.Range("E" & tRw)
    .Range("E10").copy tWs.Range("F" & tRw)
    .Range("E12").copy tWs.Range("H" & tRw)
    .Range("E4").ClearContents
    .Range("E6").ClearContents
    .Range("E8").ClearContents
    .Range("E10").ClearContents
    .Range("E12").ClearContents
End With
End Sub
```

For other methods of finding the next row look at Siddharth Rout's answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920)

And as BruceWayne stated in his comment, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920) is a great reference as to why/how to avoid using `.select`

Comment: To add to the idea that you shouldn't use `.select`, here's a [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) that has some good information on how/why to avoid it.

Comment: @BruceWayne Thanks, I was just about to go look for that reference.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to avoid the user's clipboard and to assign the values directly:

```
Sub Appt()
    Dim n&, v
    v = [transpose(offset('data entry'!e4,{0;2;4;6;8},))]
    With Sheets("appointments")
        n = .Range("d" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .[g1].Offset(n) = v(1)
        .[d1].Offset(n) = v(2)
        .[e1].Offset(n) = v(3)
        .[f1].Offset(n) = v(4)
        .[h1].Offset(n) = v(5)
    End With
    Sheets("data entry").Range("e4,e6,e8,e10,e12").ClearContents
End Sub
```